# Cmake - Add files from other sub-projects

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have two sub-projects: A and B

This is my root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Project")

add_subdirectory ("A")
add_subdirectory ("B")
```

In `/B` I have file test.h

How can I include `/B/test.h` in A ?

I have tried to add `target_include_directories(B)` in `/A/CMakeLists.txt` but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `add_subdirectory(B)` (quotes are not necessary), you must have a CMakeLists.txt in the directory B.

This CMakeLists.txt may have the following content:

```
add_library(targetB INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(targetB INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

These 2 lines create a CMake target called `targetB` with the [INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#id4) property. This is very handy for header only library. All cmake target that links with targetB will then include the CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR with is the directory `A` where your test.h is.

Then, you have `add_subdirectory(A)` with a CMakeLists.txt that may look like this (assuming you have a main in this dir A):

```
add_executable(foo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE targetB)
```

Then second line create the relation between the target foo and the target targetB and, when compiling, the path to your test.h will be set in the command line.